# Find recent backup using SMO

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, smo

Does anyone know how to find the most recent backup for a database using SMO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backup times are stored in the table msdb.dbo.backupset. Here is a routine that takes an open SQLconnection, databasename and a flag indicating whether you want full backups or any backups and returns the time of the last backup.

Note that this table sometimes gets groomed so it could indicate no backups if it has been groomed.

```
   //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Function: GetLastBackupTime
    //
    // Input
    //    sqlConnection          - An open SQLConnection to the target SQL Server
    //    DatabaseName           - Name of the database which you are interested in
    //    fullDatabaseBackupOnly - Do you want only the time of the last full backup
    //
    // Output
    //    DateTime               - DateTime.MinValue indicates no backup exists
    //                             otherwise it returns the last backup time
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DateTime GetLastBackupTime( SqlConnection sqlConnection, 
                            string        databaseName, 
                            bool          fullDatabaseBackupOnly )
{
    DateTime lastBackupTime = DateTime.MinValue;  

    string sqlTemplate = "SELECT TOP 1 backup_finish_date " +
                         "FROM msdb.dbo.backupset " + 
                         "WHERE database_name='{0}' {1} "
                         "ORDER BY backup_finish_date DESC";

    string sql = String.Format( sqlTemplate,
                                databaseName,
                                (fullDatabaseBackupOnly ) ? " AND type='D' " : "" );

    // open connection
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection, 
    {
       object retValue = _Command.ExecuteScalar();

       if ( retValue != null ) lastBackupTime = (DateTime)retValue;
    } 

    return lastBackupTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.